# How to set a minimum value that my smart contract can receive?

Tags: solidity, transactions, smart-contract-wallets

Hello iam using a fallback function so my smart contract can receive donations :

```
    fallback() payable external{            
    require(msg.value > minvalue, "ERROR !");
    uint256 sentByUser = msg.value ;  
    int requiredTokenAmount =  /* some logic /* ; 
    _token.transfer(msg.sender, uint256(requiredTokenAmount));  
   
     }
```

But i need to set a minimum value that users can send to the smart contract. I tried adding require function but it isnt working.

```
 require(msg.value > minvalue, "ERROR !");
```

Comment: Are you trying it on Remix IDE?

Comment: No iam using hardhat to deploy my dapp on a localhost, Why?

Comment: Can you add all your harhat code?